# Pass data back from a popover view controller on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, viewcontroller, popover

How can I pass data back from a PopoverViewController to the main view controller on an iPhone?

I know I'm doing something terribly wrong but I cannot figure it out.

Here is the code:
PopoverViewController.swift

```
protocol PopoverViewControllerDelegate {
    func messageData(data: AnyObject)
}

class PopoverViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var inputMessage: UITextField!
    var delegate: PopoverViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBAction func sendData(sender: AnyObject) {
        if inputMessage.text != ""{
            self.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            self.delegate?.messageData(inputMessage.text!)
        }
    }
}
```

Main ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, PopoverViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var showData: UILabel!

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // popover segue
        if segue.identifier == "popoverSegue" {

            let popoverViewController = segue.destinationViewController
            popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
        }
        // code to comunicate with data in popoverViewController
        let pvc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("popoverViewController") as! PopoverViewController
        pvc.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(pvc, animated:false, completion:nil)
    }

    func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
    }

    func messageData(data: AnyObject) {
        self.showData.text = "\(data)"
    }
}
```

With the code above I can pass data back to the main view controller without a problem, the issue is that the popover doesn't work, it just  acts like a regular `ViewController` occupying the whole screen.

The funny thing is that if I comment the following line of code the popover works but I can no longer pass data back, I can see the popover but the passing data stops working.

```
// if I comment this line 
self.presentViewController(pvc, animated:false, completion:nil)
```

I don't get any errors, one just stops working.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `prepareForSegue`, the `destinationViewController` is your `PopoverViewController`.  You need to cast it to that and set the `delegate` on that so that you can pass back data, and you need to set the `popoverPesentationController?.delegate` as well.  You don't need the rest of the code in `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // popover segue
    if segue.identifier == "popoverSegue" {
        let popoverViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PopoverViewController
        popoverViewController.delegate = self
        popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: @ vacawama - The popover doesn't work, the passing data works but the popover viewController fills the entire screen. Thanks

Comment: Did you select `presentAsPopover` when you wired up the segue in the Storyboard?

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: iPhone 6s simulator

Comment: I see, it works on the iPad. Unfortunately I need this to work on iPhone, sorry I didn't clarify that at the beginning. Original code works on iPhone.

Comment: This piece of code works on iPhone `if segue.identifier == "popoverSegue" {
       
let popoverViewController = segue.destinationViewController
popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
}`

Comment: I would also suggest you make `messageData` take a `String` instead of `AnyObject`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118162/discussion-between-fs-tigre-and-vacawama).